# OpenCL Kernel _local memory not behaving correctly

Tags: c++, opencl, julia

I have a test kernel here that I'm calling from the Julia OpenCL API.  The fact that I'm calling it from Julia isn't important, it's just what I'm using to run OpenCL, here is the code:

```
using OpenCL
const cl = OpenCL

device, ctx, queue = cl.create_compute_context()

C_buff = cl.Buffer(Float32, ctx, :w, 2)

const testkernel = """
kernel void test(global float *C)
{
    int gid = get_global_id(0);
    int lid = get_local_id(0);

    local float x;

    if (lid == 0)
    {
        x = 0.0f;
    }
    barrier(CLK_LOCAL_MEM_FENCE);

    x += 1.0f;

    barrier(CLK_LOCAL_MEM_FENCE);

    if (lid == 0)
    {
        C[gid / 2] = x;
    }
}
"""

program = cl.Program(ctx, source=testkernel) |> cl.build!
kernel = cl.Kernel(program, "test")
cl.call(queue, kernel, 4, 2, C_buff)
cl.read(queue, C_buff)
```

What I can't figure out is this returns a vector `[1.0,1.0]`, when it seems like it should return the vector `[2.0,2.0]`.  Since basically I have 4 work-items broken up into two work-groups (each containing 2 work-items).

One local float `x` is instantiated for each work-group and the first work-item in each work-group sets it to 0.  Then each work-item in the work-group adds 1 to it, and since there's two work-items in each work-group it should be 2, but when I return `C`, I get a vector of ones instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ```
> barrier(CLK_LOCAL_MEM_FENCE);
>
> x += 1.0f;
>
> barrier(CLK_LOCAL_MEM_FENCE);
> ```

Barriers aren't mutexes. You have a data race where both of the work items try to write to the same variable at the same time.

You'll have to use atomics or redesign your code.

Comment: I guess I assumed they wouldn't write at *exactly* the same time, so it would be ok.  The obvious redesign would be to instantiate a local variable `local float x[2]`, and then have each work-item in a work-group write to one or the other coordinate, and then call the barrier and then sum `x` after that.  But that seems like a non-optimal refactoring of my code, is there a better approach?

Comment: @Thoth They write at the exact same time because that's how SIMD machines work and even if they didn't [it can still happen.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition#Example)